# .htaccess mod rewrite with variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a simple redirect for my site but I'm having no luck getting it to work.

My .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(es|fr|pt|de|zh|ru|my|in|ae|bd)\.my-site\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:en]
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ http://my-site/decorators/profile/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

I want it to redirect to `http://my-site/decorators/profile/whatever if` the user browses to `http://my-site/profile/whatever`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following htaccess code

```
  RewriteCond ^([profile]+)/(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^([decorators]+)/([profile]+)/(.*)$
```

Remove the following code in your htaccess

```
  RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ http://my-site/decorators/profile/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(profile/.*)$ /my-site/decorators/$1 [NC,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(es|fr|pt|de|zh|ru|my|in|ae|bd)\.my-site\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:en]

RewriteRule (.*) $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```